# How can a module componenet use redux stores without importer having to add it's reducer to the store manually?

Tags: redux

I'm trying to write module UI components that can be imported and used by any container that wants it.  The tool I'm writing allows a user to click on an element and the information of the element should display on a seperate panel, this feels like an obvious case of using redux to update an element-key value in the store whenever a click action is used which will update the display panel.

However, I'm not certain how to use the store.  If I was writing this as part of an app I would create a reducer for the component then manually add that reducer to my reducers.js file (created by reduxbootstrap) and magic would happen.  However, as a component I expect to import into multiple other apps I would prefer not to require each app to have to import the reducer and manually add it to their list of reducers for the component to work.

Is there a cleaner way of getting my component to plug and play with an existing store?  Ideally I want someone to be able to import it and use it immediately in their UI.

The one way I know that would work is to not use redux at all, i could make the interaction work internally to the component without using redux stores at all, but it feels odd to intentionally write a non-redux component to be used in a redux app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way without you exposing your reducer to be included manually in the app root reducer. A lot of popular libraries like `redux-form` and `react-router-redux` follow this approach which I think it gives the app developers more control over their redux store.